# testng emailable-report.html in chronological order?

Tags: java, report, testng

Is it possible to get the `emailable-report.html` in chronological order from TestNG?

My test classes and methods are both being displayed out of order.

I know that `test-output/index.html` sorts chronologically, but I would like a chronological view in the emailable-report.html also

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'll need to write a custom report to do that, I am pretty sure the existing report is just iterating through the resulting objects as is, and there is no guaranteed sort order on retrieval.